# Sqlite database creation issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried to create a database in sqlite..but its not getting created.

File explorer shows no database folder in it.

Can anyone spot any error in the below given code

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, databasename, null, databaseversion);
    Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "Reached Database helper");
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_MASTER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + table_reminder_master
            + "(" + MASTER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + MASTER_TITLE
            + " TEXT," + MASTER_CONTACT_ID + " INTEGER," + MASTER_EMAIL_ID
            + " INTEGER," + MASTER_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER," + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MASTER_TABLE);
    Log.d("Table Create", "The table is created");
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + table_contactDetails
            + "(" + CONTACT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + CONTACT_NAME
            + " TEXT," + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE);
}
```

The calling class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this); // instantiation of database helper
    initializerMethod();
    reminder=new Reminder_Master();
    contact=new Contact_Details();
    Log.d("Main Acitivity", "Message");
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(saveHandler);
    }
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can't see db in file explorer. It's visible only to app. Can you insert and read something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got syntax error in your both create queries:

```
+ " INTEGER," + MASTER_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER," + ")";
```

and

```
+ " TEXT," + ")";
```

this `,` prior to `)` should not be there.

You should have checked logcat as such errors ends with exception being thrown and logged.

Comment: Have corrected the syntax error but still...no sign of database creation...yes i'm even keeping a track on logcat..it isn't showing me any error nor is it displaying the log.d entries placed in the onCreate method on DatabaseHelper

Comment: @AbhijeetSonawane `onCreate` will not be called if the DB file already exists.

Comment: @CL. I have tried a number of time by changing the database version..so i guess after changing the database version the table must be recreated

Comment: The problem still persist...but still thankz a lot to u all special @WebnetMobile

Comment: @AbhijeetSonawane With a new database version, not `onCreate` but `onUpgrade` will be called.

Comment: @CL.yes on changing the database version onUpgrade is called and I had put a call to the onCreate method at the end of the onUpgrade method..

Thankz for ur help the issue was solved there were minors mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Just creating the `DatabaseHelper` is not enough. You have to call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()`. Be sure to do so on a background thread, as you do not want to do disk I/O on the main application thread.